# Show view count posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to show popular posts in wordpress, it is work good but i can not show the number of views , please help :)

```
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
$count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
}

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

and this in the single page

```
wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
```

and this to view post

```
<?php 
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();

the_title();

endwhile;

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the count of the page you should fetch the value using the meta key via `get_post_meta()`. Within the loop you can use the `global $post` to get the current post ID.

```
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();
    // print the post title
    the_title();
    // get the count using the meta key wpb_post_views_count
    $count = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpb_post_views_count', true );
    // echo the current count
    echo $count;
endwhile;
```

You can also simplify your function that records pageviews as well. Instead of deleting and then adding, you can just use the `update_post_meta()` function which will add the value if it doesn't already exist, or update it if it does. By checking the result of `get_post_meta()` against `false` we can determine if the count needs to be initialized to 0. Once we have a value, update it to be the current value +1. Please note that on a high traffic site this isn't guaranteed to be accurate due to race conditions updating the value for multiple requests at the same time.

```
function wpb_set_post_views( $post_id ) {
    // if $count is exactly false, set it to 0, otherwise use the value from the db
    if ( false === ( $count = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpb_post_views_count', true ) ) ){
        $count = 0;
    }
    // update the value +1 pageview
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpb_post_views_count', $count+1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the post views, the first thing you have to do is to add the following code to your WordPress Theme **functions.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * Set post views count using post meta//functions.php
 */
function customSetPostViews($postID) {
    $countKey = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $countKey, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $countKey);
        add_post_meta($postID, $countKey, '1');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $countKey, $count);
    }
}
?>
```

And now we will call this function in the **single.php** to update the count value in the Database.

```
<?php 
    customSetPostViews(get_the_ID());//single.php
?>
```

Now in the same **single.php** file if we want to show the post view count, we can use this code:

```
<?php
    $post_views_count = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_views_count', true );
    // Check if the custom field has a value.
    if ( ! empty( $post_views_count ) ) {
        echo $post_views_count;
    }
?>
```

Now to show all the popular post in the descending order by post view count. use this code:

```
<?php//popular post query
    query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&posts_per_page=5&orderby=meta_value_num&
    order=DESC');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

***Happy Coding***